# ¿Como puedo agregar un id de un arreglo de usuario a otro arreglo de usuario en nestjs?

Tags: nodejs, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Hola deseo saber como puedo crear una funcion que me agregue el **_id** de un usuario en mongodb a una propiedad que es un arreglo interno de otro usuario y me retorne el usuario que se modifico.
Ej:.
Modelo  **(user.schema,ts)**

```js
export const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String;
    followers: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users', required: false}]
});
```

Array User 1

```
[
   {
     _id: "5e2b0e58c05bea0b30eee08c",
     name: "Jorge Basquez",
     followers: []
   }
]
```

Array User 2

```
[
   {
     _id: "5e2cba25ec4469229ca00b5d",
     name: "Pedro Martinez",
     followers: []
   }
]
```

Users.service.ts **(Actual)**

```
import { Injectable, Res, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { UserInterface } from './interface/users.interface';
import { NewUserDTO } from './dto/users.dto';
import { response } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    constructor(@InjectModel('users') private userModel: Model<UserInterface>) {}

    def async addFollower(userId: string, followerId: string): Promise<UserInterface> {
        const addedFollower = await this.userModel.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: userId}, {$push: {followers: followerId}});
        return addedFollower;
    }

}
```

Retorna

```
{}
```

Lo que deseo que me retorne

```
[
   {
     _id: "5e2b0e58c05bea0b30eee08c",
     name: "Jorge Basquez",
     followers: ["5e2cba25ec4469229ca00b5d"]
   }
]
```

Comment: Coloca el código de tu modelo.

Comment: Listo @gugadev Modelo agregado

Comment: Tu modelo se llama `user` o `users`? Es decir: `mongoose.model('users', usersSchema)`?

Comment: Si users @gugadev

Comment: Disculpa que no responda a los comentarios rápidamente es que me falla el net, cualquier cosa me desconectare y en unas horas me conectare nuevamente @gugadev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo la siguiente estructura para lograr lo que quieres:

```
//...Dentro de tu controler

const datos = req.body //Aqui deben estar los datos a modificar

User.findById(idDelUsuario)
.exec()
.then(usuario=>{
    if(!usuario) trhow 'No existe el usuario'

    usuario.followers.push(datos.newFollower)
    return usuario.save()

})
.then(usuarioGuardado=> {
   //...Tu respuesta normal
})
.catch(err=>//...Manejo de errores)
```

Con esta estructura logras un mayor control de las validaciones. Mongoose se encargara de actualizar solo los campos que se hayan modificado y obtendrás las ventajas de poder seguir utilizando los middlewares de`mongoose con naturalidad. También cumplimos con retornar el usuario modificado.